# If "NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments", how do I compare and match values of a table to a longer list of names in R?

Tags: r, match, na

Thanks for helping me out here!
I have a list of 71,483 user names ("ALL") and a dataframe ("ActDred") with Twitter data.

I want to count how often a user 
a) posted a tweet and 
b) replied to a post, 
then adding this number to the list of users. Some users don't tweet or reply, I would add NA for them.

That's what I've done and it worked for a) but not for b). For b), I'm getting the error: "NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments".

```
#a)
#Select only Tweet edges
Tw<-ActDred[ActDred$Relationship=="Tweet",]
#Number of tweets of each user
NTw<-table(Tw$`Vertex 1`)

#Match number of tweets to list of all nodes
SA_NumTw <- rep(NA, length(ALL))
SA_NumTw[match(names(NTw), ALL)]<-NTw

#b)
#Select only Reply edges
Re <- ActDred[ActDred$Relationship=="Replies to",]
#Number of replies of each user
NRe<-table(Re$`Vertex 1`)

#Match number of replies to list of all nodes
SA_NumRe <- rep(NA, length(ALL))
SA_NumRe[match(names(NRe), ALL)] <- NRe
```

For b), I get

> "Error in SA_NumRe[which] <- NRe :    NAs are not allowed in
>   subscripted assignments"

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing here and why it works for a) but not for b)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just a passing comment... Maybe assign 0 instead of NA if a user doesn't tweet or reply?

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, also with 99 but nothing works, I still get the same error. The weird thing is, it used to work before. I used exactly the same code on almost the same data a few weeks ago.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!
There were a few users that replied but that are not in the ALL list. I removed them first and then continued and it worked :)

Here is what I did:

```
Re <- ActDred[ActDred$Relationship=="Replies to",]
RbutA <- setdiff(Re$`Vertex 1`, ALL) 
# there are 19 repliers that are not in the ALL list, hence I get the error and need to eliminate the 19 users first
Re2 <- Re[Re$`Vertex 1` %in% ALL,1:8]
#Number of replies of each user
NRe<-table(Re2$`Vertex 1`)

#Match number of replies to list of all nodes
SA_NumRe <- rep(NA, length(ALL))
SA_NumRe[match(names(NRe), ALL)] <- NRe
```

Now, I don't get an error anymore :)